# Unable to backup and restore on Solr Cloud

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I'm trying to test a backup and restore of a collection on SolrCloud but having no joy (Version 6.6.5).

I'm doing a backup with:

```
curl -f "http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/admin/collections?action=BACKUP&name=$BACKUP_NAME&collection=$TARGET_COLLECTION&location=$BACKUP_LOCATION&wt=json"
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":6370},"success":{"solr-2.search-solr.svc.cluster.local:8080_solr":{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":6143}}}}
```

But then I'm trying to run a restore:

```
curl -v -f "http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/admin/collections?action=RESTORE&name=at-uk&collection=at-uk-restore&location=/tmp&wt=json"
* About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /solr/admin/collections?action=RESTORE&name=at-uk&collection=at-uk-restore&location=/tmp&wt=json HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
> Accept: */*
>
* The requested URL returned error: 500 Server Error
* Closing connection 0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 500 Server Error
```

And in the solr logs:

```
ERROR 2019-02-11 13:24:23,547 [OverseerThreadFactory-42-thread-5-processing-n:solr-2.search-solr.svc.cluster.local:8080_solr][SolrException.java:159] : Collection: at-uk-restore operation: restore failed:java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.solr.cloud.RestoreCmd.call(RestoreCmd.java:110)
        at org.apache.solr.cloud.OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.processMessage(OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.java:226)
        at org.apache.solr.cloud.OverseerTaskProcessor$Runner.run(OverseerTaskProcessor.java:464)
        at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:229)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

ERROR 2019-02-11 13:24:23,555 [qtp157456214-655][SolrException.java:159] : null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException
        at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleResponse(CollectionsHandler.java:300)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.invokeAction(CollectionsHandler.java:237)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleRequestBody(CollectionsHandler.java:215)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:173)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdmin(HttpSolrCall.java:748)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:729)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:510)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:361)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Is there any chance you have run out of disk space during the backup?

Comment: Nope not at all, literally 90% free!  The error happens during the restore anyway, not the backup.

Comment: Any other errors in the solr log file where you see the error above?

Comment: Nothing at all just those above

Comment: At this point I could only suggest reaching out to the Solr/Lucene mailing list http://lucene.apache.org/solr/community.html#mailing-lists-irc Sorry I could not be more help

Comment: For anyone else coming here, we resolved this by upgrading to solr7